# Disable Fuzzy Search in Visual Studio Solution Explorer (not VS Code)?

Tags: visual-studio

Visaul Studio Solution Explorer's search function used to be my most improtant way of finding things in my solution, but at some point they introduced a fuzzy search and now almost every search results in dozens of irrelevant hits.

For example, if I search for "money" one of the hits it gives me is "Mode". Another is "None". This is not even remotely useful.

Is there any way to disable this and go back to a simple match?